# how to vectorize this?

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for way to vectorize this :

```py
for x in range(1,N+1):
  mul3ou5 = "inf"*(x%3 == 0)+"luans"*(x%5==0) 
  print str(x)*(mul3ou5 =="")+mul3ou5
```

The idea is to use a numpy array and replace the for loop by one operation on the numpy array `numpy.array(range(100))`

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of the input and output? It's currently hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In English we call this game FizzBuzz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
# generating data set (N: number, S: resulting string)
df = pd.DataFrame({'N': np.arange(1,N+1), 'S': np.arange(1,N+1) },columns=['N','S'])
# convert col. S to string
df['S']=df['S'].apply(str)
# set empty string if x mod 3 == 0 or x mod 5 == 0
df['S'][(df['N'].mod(3)==0) | (df['N'].mod(5)==0)] = ""
# set mod 3 == 0 condition
df['S'][(df['N'].mod(3)==0)] = "inf"
# mod 5 == 0
df['S'][(df['N'].mod(5)==0)] = df['S']+"luans"
```

The result is in `df['S']`.

Answer (score 2):

While @morningsun's answer is great, another option is this (using [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, N+1)
s = x.astype('S8')
s[x % 3 == 0] = 'inf'
s[x % 5 == 0] = 'luans'
s[x % 15 == 0] = 'influans'
```

which I find more intuitive, as it preserves the explicit modulus (`%`) operation.

Answer (score 1):

Assign to slices:

```
S = numpy.arange(1, N+1).astype('S8')
S[2::3] = 'inf'
S[4::5] = 'luans'
S[14::15] = 'influans'
```